# Fibonacci sequence in tiling with "einstein" aperiodical "hat" monotiles

Tags: sequences-and-series, tiling

Here is part of a tiling, from [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~csk/hat/app.html](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecsk/hat/app.html) - 4-th level at South West region. I colored obvious trivial patterns of some dark blue hats: red, green and orange. Can those be proved by induction after suitable formalization of the substitution rules? The interesting pattern, in purple and orange, starts with this sequence of orange hats: 1, 4, 12. What is the general term of this sequence and is it familiar?

[image]

EDIT: A preliminary analysis of some recurrences suggests that the sequence of positions of purple hats are Fibonacci numbers: they are $\phi_{2n} \ \ (1,3,8,21,55,...)$. A proof of this is needed.

Comment: The lines you notice have $a_i$ normal and $a_{i-1}$ flipped tiles, where $(a_i)$ is the sequence 0, 1, 4, 12, 33,.... These numbers appear to be $F(2n+1)-1$ (OEIS A027941), where $F(n)$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number. // How do you decide which tiles in an orange line to make purple?